# Perl script couldn't connect to MS SQL using ODBC: "Connection string is not valid"

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc, connection-string

the script test.pl

```
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:ODBC:" .
    "Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1};" .
    "Server=10.3.0.241;" .
    "Database=TEST;" .
    "UID=test;" .
    "PWD=test123"
);
```

the result

```
DBI connect('Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1};Server=10.3.0.241,0;Database=TEST;UID=test;PWD=test123','',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (SQL-HYT00) [state was HYT00 now 08001]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Connection string is not valid [87].  (SQL-08001)
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (SQL-08001) at ./test.pl line 6.
```

owner of the server said: you can't connect to port 1433, we are using SSMS and the port will be automatic

Comment: "we are using SSMS and the port will be automatic" is utter nonsense. Find out what protocols they have enabled on the server (they can check this from SQL Configuration Manager if they have no clue) as they'll need TCP/IP enabled for you to be able to connect from Linux. Also, if it is a "Named Instance" instead of a default instance then the SQL Browser service will need to be enabled, running, and accessible on udp/1434 so that connecting clients can find out what tcp port the named instance is accessible via.

Answer (score 0):

Server=10.3.0.241;
became
Server=10.3.0.241\MSSQL;

then my linux can communicate with the windows server via udp/1443 and
understand each other on which tcp port to continue communication.